# Spark, What does groupby return?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

what's the return value of `groupBy` and `agg` in spark?
(this was one of the confusing part of pandas, and I never got it, and I guess it is similar here with spark)

```
df.groupBy("col1").agg(max("col2").alias("col2_max"))
```

it seems even if it looks like regular dataframe when you do `.show()` on it, I believe it is not a dataframe. (because if you do another `.agg` after the initial `.agg` things get weird

So what does `groupBy` return and `agg` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Spark documentation, the `Dataframe.groupBy` method returns a `GroupData` object which basically has aggregated methods like `agg`, `count`, `sum`, `avg`, etc. The `agg` method (and the other ones) return a `DataFrame`

For further details, review the following documentation links: http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.groupBy and http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData

Hope this helps